# linking properties

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

hei,

assume that i have this code:

```
        <StackPanel>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Height="400" Width="235">
        <Image x:Name="image" Source="/SplashScreenImage.jpg" Stretch="Fill">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>

            </Image>
        <TextBlock Canvas.ZIndex="1"  Text="TextBlock"   Canvas.Left="61" Canvas.Top="150"/>
    </Canvas>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" >Test</TextBlock>

    </StackPanel>
```

What i want to do is the canvas's width and height properties linked to image. something like this:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" Height="{image Height}" Width="{image Width"}>
```

since I have been previously using Qt Quick and this is quite easy, they call it property binding. I am wondering if this is possible in XAML as well ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution, example:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Margin="10" x:Name="txtData" />
  <TextBlock Margin="10" 
             Text="{Binding ElementName=txtData, 
                            Path=Text}" />
</StackPanel>
```